# Getting data from WordPress widget to modify post content

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am trying to create a widget that accepts paragraph numbers and inserts some HTML (for ads) after those specified paragraphs on a post. For example, if the user inputs 1 in the first field and 3 in the second field I want some markup I defined to appear after those paragraphs.

I've created the widget and managed to make it work when I manually create the array via

```php
$paragraph_targets = array('1', '3');
```

inside the `insert_post_ads` method.

The bit I'm stuck on is how to get the paragraph numbers from widget into the `insert_post_ads` method.

Full code is below.

```php
class Ad_Inserter extends WP_Widget
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'ad_inserter',
            'Ad Inserter',
            [
                'description' => 'Inserts ads in post content',
            ]
        );
        add_filter('the_content', [
            $this,
            'insert_post_ads',
        ]);
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {
        $instance = array_merge([
            'ad_1' => '',
            'ad_2' => '',
        ], $instance);
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('ad_1')); ?>">Ad 1 Position</label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('ad_1')); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('ad_1')); ?>"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($instance['ad_1']); ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('ad_2')); ?>">Ad 2 Position</label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('ad_2')); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('ad_2')); ?>"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($instance['ad_2']); ?>">
        </p>

        <?php
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {

    }

    public function insert_post_ads($content)
    {
        if (is_single() && !is_admin()) {
            $paragraph_targets = [
                '1',
                '3',
            ];
            sort($paragraph_targets);

            return $this->insert_after_paragraph($paragraph_targets, $content);
        }

        return $content;
    }

    // Go through paragraphs and insert ads
    public function insert_after_paragraph($paragraph_targets, $content)
    {
        $ad_ids = [
            'advert-1',
            'advert-2',
        ];

        $closing_p = '</p>';
        $paragraphs = explode($closing_p, $content);

        foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
            if (trim($paragraph)) {
                $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
            }

            if ($paragraph_targets[0] == $index + 1) {
                $ad_code = '<div id="'.$ad_ids[0].'" class="advert">**** AD ****</div>';
                $paragraphs[$index] .= $ad_code;
                array_shift($paragraph_targets);
                array_shift($ad_ids);
            }
        }

        return implode('', $paragraphs);
    }

}

add_action('widgets_init', 'registerWidget');
function registerWidget()
{
    register_widget('Ad_Inserter');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In absence of a better answer, I would probably use a global variable to store it in. Assuming that `widgets_init` is fired before the post is created.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-php/

**Update**

When your filter is called/applied, you only receive the `$content` object, and since `$paragraph_targets` is not part of that, I wouldn't know how to get to it other than making it a global var.

Just to be sure, can you explain the flow of what should happen? A user enters paragraph numbers, after this the page reloads with the changes added in? Is it not supposed to be stored? If so, then shouldn't `$paragraph_targets` be stored as post metadata?

Then you would probably get it in `insert_post_ads($content)` like so:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
get_post_meta( $post_id,'paragraph_targets');
```

(Untested)

Comment: To explain further the user would activate the widget via the widget page. This is so the widget gets activated for all posts. Once the user enters the paragraph numbers any posts that loaded from there on has the ads automatically added after specified paragraph numbers.

Comment: I think post meta may be better suited if I wanted to customize the positioning per post whereas in my case I want one setting for all posts. I managed to find what I was after: `get_option($this->option_name)`. This returns the widget values as well other data which I needed to remove. Although what you suggested wasn't quite what I was looking for it helped me find what I was after so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution was `get_option($this->option_name)` which returns a multi-dimensional array containing the paragraph target values I was after from the widget.

I had to create a new method to extract the values from the multi-dimensional array and put them in a basic array.

Solution below.

```
        public function insert_post_ads($content) {
            if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
                // $paragraph_targets = array('2', '5');
                $paragraph_widget_values = get_option($this->option_name);
                $paragraph_targets = $this->get_array_values($paragraph_widget_values);

                array_pop($paragraph_targets); // Remove _multiwidget from array
                sort($paragraph_targets);
                return $this->insert_after_paragraph( $paragraph_targets, $content );
            }
            return $content;
        }

        // Get values from multi-dimensional array
        public function get_array_values($array) { 
            if (!is_array($array)) { 
                return FALSE; 
            } 
            $result = array(); 
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
                if (is_array($value)) { 
                    $result = array_merge($result, $this->get_array_values($value)); 
                } 
                else { 
                    $result[$key] = $value; 
                } 
            }

            return array_values($result); 
        }
```